# Как показать картинку, после возникновения if события?

Tags: javascript, функции, if, img

Как сделать так, чтобы при срабатывании условий:
1)"if ((this.years - 1950)%12 == 0 )
alert ( this.name +' You are a Tiger!'); " , сработал метод this.show=function () и показал картинку  id="img" src="r.jpg";
2)"if ((this.years - 1951)%12 == 0 )
alert ( this.name +' You are a Tiger!'); " , сработал метод this.show=function () и показал картинку id="img1" src="tt.jpg";
Ставить this.show=function () после каждого if не получается.

```
        <script>
function An (name)
{this.name = name;
this.years = +prompt('What year were you born in?');
  this.run=function ()
{if ((this.years - 1950)%12 == 0 )
alert ( this.name +' You are a Tiger!');

if ((this.years - 1951)%12 == 0 )
alert ( this.name +' You are a Rabbit!'); };};

this.show=function (){
document.getElementById('img').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('img1').style.display = 'block';};

var an = new An ('Losi');
an.run();
an.show();
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="show(); return false;">Показать</a><br />
<img id="img" src="r.jpg" style="display: none;"/>
<img id="img1" src="tt.jpg" style="display: none;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Уже все сделано:

```
<script>
function An (name)
{this.name = name;
this.years = +prompt('What year were you born in?');

 this.run=function ()
{if ((this.years - 1950)%12 == 0 )
{alert ( this.name +' You are a Tiger!');
return 1;}

if ((this.years - 1951)%12 == 0 )
{alert ( this.name +' You are a Rabbit!'); 
return 2;}}}

this.show=function ()
{if(u==1)
document.getElementById('img').style.display = 'block';
if(u==2)
document.getElementById('img1').style.display = 'block';}

var an = new An ('Losi');
u=an.run();
an.show();
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="show(); return false;">Показать</a><br />
<img id="img" src="r.jpg" style="display: none;"/>
<img id="img1" src="tt.jpg" style="display: none;"/>
```